# stepAIC handling of multinom models

Tags: r, regression, nnet

I am seeing some weird behavior with the `stepAIC` function in the `MASS` package when dealing with multinomial logistic models. Here is some sample code:

```
library(nnet)
library(MASS)
example("birthwt")
race.model <- multinom(race ~ smoke, bwt)
race.model2 <- stepAIC(race.model, k = 2)
```

In this case `race.model` and `race.model2` have identical terms; `stepAIC` did not prune anything. However, I need to query certain attributes of the models, and I get an error with `race.model2`:

```
formula(race.model)[2]
```

returns `race()` but

```
formula(race.model2)[2]
```

gives the error:

```
    Error in terms.formula(newformula, specials = names(attr(termobj, "specials"))) : 
invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

This behavior only seems to occur when `stepAIC` does not remove terms from the model. In the following code, terms are removed by `stepAIC`, and both models can be properly queried:

```
race.big <- multinom(race ~ ., bwt)
race.big2 <- stepAIC(race.big, k = 2)
formula(race.big)[2]
formula(race.big2)[2]
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `formula()[2]`? `race.model` and `race.model2` are different classes of objects and `formula()` is a generic function which returns different things for the two class types. What exactly is the desired behavior? There may be better ways to get what you want.

Comment: I would like to do `anova`. `anova(update(race.model, '. ~ . - smoke'), race.model)` works but `anova(update(race.model2, '. ~ . - smoke'), race.model2)` gives an error. Using `traceback()`, it looks like the issue is in `formula()`.

Comment: What are the two classes of objects? `class(race.model)` and `class(race.model2)` returns the same class type: multinom nnet.